# Regex in Angular

Tags: regex

I currently have:

```
/(\S+:\/\/\S+)/ig
```

I want to cover all of these cases

*`client.wildfyre.net`
*`client.wildfyre.net/324234/`
`http://client.wildfyre.net`
`https://client.wildfyre.net`
`http://client.wildfyre.net/34534`
`https://client.wildfyre.net/34534`
*`WildFyre.net`
*`WildFyre.net/324234/`
*`www.WildFyre.net`
*`www.WildFyre.net/23423/`
`http://WildFyre.net`
`http://WildFyre.net/324234/`
`http://www.WildFyre.net`
`http://www.WildFyre.net/23423/`
`https://WildFyre.net`
`https://WildFyre.net/324234/`
`https://www.WildFyre.net`
`https://www.WildFyre.net/23423/`
`http://foo.co.uk/`
`http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar`
`https://mediatemple.net`

Ones that are star'ed aren't found

Comment: What is this functionality for if I may ask?

Comment: Is it OK to cover cases not listed? If so, what are you actually trying to cover? URLs?

Comment: @CameronGilbert Please check if my edit is ok. Added two more `*` before the ones starting with `www.` as they [were not matched either](https://regex101.com/r/diIFFy/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently working for me on [regexr](http://regexr.com/3gfve) with very preliminary testing:

`/\S+\.\S+/ig`- Words separated by a period

`/\S+[A-Z]\.\w\S+/ig` - Words separated by period plus everything attached to them

`/\S+[A-Z]\.\w\S+\b/ig` - Ignore trailing special characters

If you want to grab all the addresses, even those without the `://` prefix, then I believe `//` can't be a required sequence. I'm new to regex, so take this with a grain of salt. Note that without more input from OP this could be grabbing unintended occurrences.